# Sending a review via the url

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form that is on a PHP Page and consists of 2 elements.

- A rating dropdown box (out of 5)
- A comment box (Text Box)

and a submit button.

I want to place the content of these two into the URL, how do I do this?

An example would be:

```
example.php?rating=4&comment=asdasdasda%20asdasdas%20
```

The form is:

```
   <form action="" method="get"> 
        <label>Rating:</label> 
        <select class="form_input"> 
            <option value="1">1</option> 
            <option value="2">2</option> 
            <option value="3">3</option> 
            <option value="4">4</option> 
            <option value="5">5</option> 
        </select><br /> 
        <label>Comments:</label> 
        <textarea class="form_textarea"></textarea> 
        <input type="submit" class="form_submit_right" value="Submit" /> 
        </form>
```

Comment: As Nick says, this is the default behaviour for a GET-method form. But beware that really long URLs might be truncated - I think I've seen a 2,000 character limit before - so you really ought to restrict the text length in your form if you're going to do this. Or use POST instead.

Comment: ..and remember to escape the input your using from `$_GET` to avoid XSS attacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to put the values that you entered into the drop-down and the text input into the URL like `?dropdown_name=dropdown_value&textbox_name=textbox_value` then you need to specify `GET` as the form method in your form opening tag:

```
<form action="" method="get">
   ...
</form>
```

**EDIT**: The reason the form isn't working if because your controls (the `select` and `textarea`) need to have `name` attributes.  The `name` defines the `key` in the `key=value` pair.

Your form should look like:

```
<form action="" method="get"> 
    <label>Rating:</label> 
    <select name="rating" class="form_input"> 
        <option value="1">1</option> 
        <option value="2">2</option> 
        <option value="3">3</option> 
        <option value="4">4</option> 
        <option value="5">5</option> 
    </select><br /> 
    <label>Comments:</label> 
    <textarea name="comment" class="form_textarea"></textarea> 
    <input type="submit" class="form_submit_right" value="Submit" /> 
</form>
```

Comment: When I try this it doesn't seem to display what I have entered?

Comment: Post more code in your question, then we can see what's going wrong.

Comment: @Xerting: you've missed the `name` attributes on the form controls.  I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Send it with the GET method, like

```
<form action="{$PHP_SELF}" method="get">
```

Or you can use a bit of Javascript to dynamically create the link.